# want to count post per day in sql with codeigniter

Tags: mysql

i have database with post and post with time.i want to count post per day. how can i do that? i was able to do that if my post_time has only date not time.

My Table Structure

> post - post_time( in yyyy-mm-mm h:m:s )

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY DAY(datetimecolumn)`?

Comment: thanks for answering . i just realize that i was using wrong column in joint.

Comment: No problem, glad you've got is solved.